# Change magento cloud project repository

Tags: magento2, repository

we need to change the repo that a magento cloud project uses. Like if we were migrating from GitHub to BitBucket. How could we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just create the new repository and stay with the two and then delete the previous repository

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this article to change your repo for cloud projects.

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/integrations/github-integration.html

For eg.

> magento-cloud integration:add --type=github --project=yourprojectid
> --token=yourtoken **--repository=Magento/teamrepo**